# golang mongo-go-driver can't increment a previously nil value

Tags: mongodb, go, increment, mongo-go

I have this kind of query to run. Running this query manually return OK with upsertedCount = 1 when the key not exist

```
db.test.update({Key: 'random-id'}, {$inc: {Version: 1}},{upsert: true})
```

I try to convert it to mongodb golang version below

```
client, _ := mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017/"))
coll := client.Database("test").Collection("test")
filter := bson.D{bson.E{"Key", "random-id"}}
docs := bson.D{bson.E{"$inc", bson.E{"Version", 1}}}

upsert := true
result, err := coll.UpdateOne(
  context.TODO(),
  filter, docs,
  &options.UpdateOptions{Upsert: &upsert})
if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}
fmt.Print(result)
```

Unfortunately, this query returns error

```
multiple write errors: [{write errors: [{Cannot increment with non-numeric argument: {key: "Version"}}]}, {<nil>}]
```

Why can't it works? It seems that the driver trying to increment it without sending it to mongo

**Edit:**

1. change the schema case to Upper, to follow the go code
2. Use simpler version of code

Comment: Maybe `Version` type in the schema is `non-numeric`

Comment: In the Go version, `"Version"` and `"Key"` should be lowercased, just as in your mongo command.

Comment: @Eklavya I havent set the schema, that's why direct query works

Comment: @icza ah sorry, I want to publish the `Key` and `Version` public, so I set it to uppercase. Gonna update the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `docs` value. It's supposed to be a valid document. [`bson.D`](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#D) is a valid document if all its elements are valid. It has an element with `$inc` key, which requires its value to be a valid document too. [`bson.E`](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#E) is not a document, it's an element of a document.

Change your `docs` to this:

```
docs := bson.D{bson.E{"$inc", bson.D{bson.E{"Version", 1}}}}
```

And it will work.

If order is not important (it isn't in your case), alternatively you may use [`bson.M`](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#M) to model your `filter` and `docs` like this:

```
filter := bson.M{"Key": "random-id"}
docs := bson.M{
    "$inc": bson.M{"Version": 1},
}
```

This is much simpler, clearer and more intuitive.

Also note that there are builders for the options. Obtain your [`options.UpdateOptions`](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options#UpdateOptions) value safely, idiomatically and clearly like this:

```
options.Update().SetUpsert(true)
```

Comment: Thank you! Just one clarification I want to know, a single-key object should still be wrapped in bson.D?

Comment: @aaron It's the `$inc`. In your mongo command you use `{}` to specify what you want to increment. That `{}` is a document, so in Go you have to use `bson.D` or `bson.M` for it. Look at it from a way that each `{}` is a document.